# React State management

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to React. On going through the React tutorial, I understand the need to lift the state to the parent component which ensures that the children components can stay in sync and can feed off the major chunk of data residing in the state of the parent. But then , with changing data, won't the setState in the parent fire off the re-rendering of all the children components, decreasing UI performance ? Without using flux or redux, which is the best way to position the state in a react application ?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org). Mobx wraps JS objects in a way that lets you subscribe to changes of properties, and then this can tie into react and update components based on those changes. Caveat: it's not as popular as Redux, and it doesn't have the "pure function" benefits of redux's reducer pattern. But it is pretty slick, and uses less boilerplate than Redux.

Comment: In this case, both Redux and Mobx are suitable. Redux is the most popular lib in [React State Management Libraries](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/awesome-react-state-management) list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change a component's state, it triggers a re-render for that component.

The re-render will create a new set of virtual elements (returned from the `render` function), which React uses to represent the new state of the DOM. However, unless there are differences between the virtual DOM and the real DOM, nothing will be changed.

The fact that React's virtual elements are simply lightweight object representations of actual HTML elements makes it fast enough that in most cases, you don't even need to think about the performance cost of calling `render` for child components.

If, however, you do find yourself with a child component that has a particularly expensive render function—you can prevent it from always re-rendering by [implementing `shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). This allows you to specify with fine grained control, which changes in props or state will actually trigger a component to update.

The other approach is to build a custom state management solution which explicitly ties your components together.

```
let state = { count: 0 };
let listenForState = null;

function ComponentA() {
  let onClick = () => {
    state.count += 1;
    if (listenForState) listenForState(state);
  };

  return <button onClick={onClick}>+</button>;
}

class ComponentB extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = state;
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    listenForState(state => this.setState(state));
  }
  render() {
    return <span>{this.state.count}</span>;
  }
}
```

However this quite quickly gets out of hand, and there aren't many situations where it would be better than just lifting state up to a shared parent.

If you find that your state driven child components are nested too deeply in the stateful parent, then it's time to look at Redux instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your mostly right. But you dont need to pass the **state** of the component to the children, you r passing only **props**, its not actually the same, because changing of props doesnt need to rerender your component.

There is amazing method in the component lifecycle, called `shouldComponentUpdate`, default its return true if only shallow equality of states objects are false (if refs are different - thats why mutate of state will not rerender component). And you can also implement this method by yourself, comparing your props to check if you need an update or not. There is a scheme how would it work.

[image]

And also, react will not rerender element if the virtual DOM was not changed. So this way you can rerender component if only **his props** is changed, but if you need to change props of its children - you must rerender **current**.

Basicly, because of these there is an advice to pull the state of application from top to the *leafs* component (which returns most of html). You can read about optimization more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html).

---

And must to say :

**Your code must become a spaghetti**

If you will have a lot of components, which have a lot of events, based on state, so if you need some complex architecture, use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) or some other global state manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking **only** for a State Management library, check Duix (https://www.npmjs.com/package/duix).

Redux solves a lot of problems (adding complexity). If you only want to improve the State Management, just take a look at Duix.

PS.: I created that library